# Resolved: Nodejs | Typescript | Router | ts-node-esm: Receiving: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, package.json, tsconfig

I could really use some help. I'm trying to create my first nodejs/react app with typescript. I am simply trying to import routes from `/src/routes/tickerRouter` to `server/index.ts` but I am running into an error.

Error:

```
/.../node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module '/.../react-node-app/server/src/routes/tickerRouter' imported from /.../react-node-app/server/index.ts
```

What I've done so far:

- setup all my files with `.ts` instead of `.js`
- tried adding `.js` to the import line in `index.ts`, while keeping the actual file extension `.ts`
- running start with `ts-node-esm server/index.ts`
- Added "type": "module" in package.json.
- Using `export default` instead of `module.exports =`
- Spent way too long scouring the web for answers :'(

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it turns out

`tried adding .js to the import line in index.ts, while keeping the actual file extension .ts`

worked. It just caused the same error in another file. For whatever reason, ts files need to be imported with the .js extension.

Comment: I also have the same situation, where importing .js files works. Did you find a way to resolve this?

Comment: maybe try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebx

Comment: Wow, did not expect that to work. Feels like a hack, but good enough for my use-case.